# How to a apply a macro that's for one cell to multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that add the same cell based on the worksheet name, here's the code:

```
Sub Addem()
Dim ws As Worksheet
x = 0
For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name Like "*Fvar" Then
    x = x + ws.Range("G12").Value
End If
Next ws
Sheets("Summary-Fvar2").Range("G12").Value = x
End Sub
```

How can I format this macro to apply it to several cells location separately? (H12, N12, H33, N33 etc...)

When I tried defining the range name and adding all the cell locations I wanted to apply it to it sum every cell in the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would apply a formula like that. This code replaces your Sub Addem

```
Sub AddCell(ByVal myCell As String, ByVal target As Range, ByVal pattern As String)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myFormula As String

        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Name Like pattern Then
                myFormula = myFormula & ws.Name & "!" & myCell & ","
            End If
        Next

        myFormula = Left(myFormula, Len(myFormula) - 1)
        target.Formula = "=SUM(" & myFormula & ")"

End Sub

Sub TestIt()
     AddCell "G12", Sheets("Summary-Fvar2").Range("G12"), "Fav*"    
End Sub
```

The next code is for an array of cells

```
Sub AddCellV(ByVal vCell As Variant, ByVal target As Range, ByVal pattern As String)
            Dim ws As Worksheet

        Dim myFormula As String
        Dim i As Long
            For i = LBound(vCell) To UBound(vCell)
                For Each ws In Worksheets
                    If ws.Name Like pattern Then
                        myFormula = myFormula & ws.Name & "!" & vCell(i) & ","
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            myFormula = Left(myFormula, Len(myFormula) - 1)
            target.Formula = "=SUM(" & myFormula & ")"

End Sub

Sub TestIt()                
      AddCellV Array("G12", "H12", "N12", "H33", "N33"), Sheets("Summary-Fvar2").Range("G12"), "Fav*"                
End Sub
```

By the comment of the TO AddCell needs to applied multiple times like that

```
Sub AddCellMultiple(ByVal vCell As Variant, _
                            ByVal targetSh As Worksheet, _
                            ByVal pattern As String)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(vCell) To UBound(vCell)
        AddCell vCell(i), targetSh.Range(vCell(i)), pattern
    Next

End Sub


Sub TestMultiple()
    AddCellMultiple Array("G12", "H12", "N12", "H33", "N33"), Sheets("Summary-Fvar2"), "Fav*"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response but I think your misconstrue my question, I don't want to add the all the (G12,H12, N12, etc) together I want to the do the process separately.   Add on the G12 replace G12 than add all the H12 and replace H12.  Is there a way to tweak your code for this.

Comment: Just to make sure I got you right: The AddCell is correct and you want to apply AddCell for G12, H12, N12 etc separately?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to total of them all in one cell I want the totals in the respective cells.  Add all sheets with the sheet name criteria for G12, and put it in the summary than do the same for H12 and N12 etc.  Thanks for you help

Comment: I edited the post and added another Sub which should fulfill your request

Comment: I get an error and it highlights Addcell in your code

Comment: You have the code for AddCell and AddCellMultiple in your Module? What is the error message saying?

Comment: Thanks so much I didn't have Add Cell in the module

Answer (score 1):

If you want the cells added separately, you could cycle through an array, viz

```
Sub Addem()

Dim ws As Worksheet, x() As Long, v, i As Long

v = Array("G12", "H12", "N12", "H33", "N33") 'amend to suit
ReDim x(UBound(v))

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "*Fvar" Then
        For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
            x(i) = x(i) + ws.Range(v(i)).Value
        Next i
    End If
Next ws

For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
    Sheets("Summary-Fvar2").Range(v(i)).Value = x(i)
Next i

End Sub
```